# Yii, Backbone save(), data did not passed through $_POST

Tags: php, post, backbone.js, yii, synchronization

This is my JavaScript in index.php:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            myID: "",
            myName: ""
        },
        urlRoot: 'testAjaxAdd',
        sync: function(method, model, options) {
            options = options || {};
            options['data'] = {};

            options.data["myID"] = model.get("myID");
            options.data["myName"] = model.get("myName");

            options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);

            return Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });

    MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
        render: function(){
            var template = _.template($('#add-owner-template').html(), {});
            this.$el.html(template);
        },
        events: {
            'submit .create-owner-form': 'saveOwner'
        },
        saveOwner: function(events) {
            var myName= $('input#myName').val();

            var owner = new MyModel({
                'myID': "111",
                'myName': myName
            });

            owner.save({},{
                success: function(model, response, options) {

                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(response); // show $_POST from actionSaveOwner in Controller
                    console.log(model.toJSON()); // show model
                    console.log(model.get('myID')); // show owner dbcID
                    console.log(model.get('myName')); // show owner userID
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(options)); // show options
                    console.log(options.data["myID"]); // this is shown undefined in console
                    console.log(options.data["myName"]); // this is shown undefined in console

                },
                error: function(model, response, options) {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(model.toJSON());
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

I have put the code below in very first line within my javascript codes:

```
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
```

This is my html part of the form, it also a javascript template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="add-owner-template">
<form class='create-owner-form'>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn createcontbutton">Create</button>
</form>
</script>
```

This is my very simple action in Controller to test out if my backbone works or not:

```
public function actionTestAjaxAdd()
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    echo CJSON::encode($_POST);

}
```

However, this is what I see from console in `POST` tab:

```
Parameters  application/x-www-form-urlencoded   Do not sort
{"myID":"111","myName":"i...
```

But, the $_POST in controller action is nothing when i display it back in console from response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this myself using `file_get_contents("php://input")` .